# How to Control 2-wire Rotary-Gear Linear Actuator

Tags: arduino-uno, motor

Any ideas how to control a 2-wire DC 5V 10mm Stroke Mini Linear Actuator based Rotary Gear Motor? Most linear actuators (aside from solenoids) are controlled via 3-4 wires. Do I need a separate motor controller for the actuator to control it via an Arduino Uno?

[image]

Comment: Second the H-bridge suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that's little more than a geared brushed DC motor with a fancy "nut" on it. So yes, you will need any standard motor driver rated for the correct voltage / current (an H-bridge).